# How is a symbol name generated in a .so (shared library) file?

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries

How are the names that appear for a symbol generated in a shared library file? For example, when using elfread -Ws to read the symbols in the  libutils.so file (android system utils library), I get several symbol names of the format:

```
_ZN7android10VectorImpl14insertVectorAtERKS0_j
```

etc. How do you decipher this symbol name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be a mangled name, e.g., for C++, and you can make better sense of those using the `-C` option of [`nm`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html):

> **`-C`**
>   **`--demangle`**[=style]
>   Decode (demangle) low-level symbol names into user-level names. Besides removing any initial underscore prepended by the system, this makes C++ function names readable. Different compilers have different mangling styles. The optional demangling style argument can be used to choose an appropriate demangling style for your compiler. See [c++filt](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html#c_002b_002bfilt), for more information on demangling.

When using `nm` on shared libraries, this option shows their symbols:

> **`-D`**
>   **`--dynamic`**
>      Display the dynamic symbols rather than the normal symbols. This is only meaningful for dynamic objects, such as certain types of shared libraries.

Comment: libutils.so is in elf format so nm reports no symbols.

Comment: @shaveenk You can pipe output from `readelf` to `c++filt` to achieve the same effect as `nm -C`